# Why is the learning rate already very small (1e-05) while the model convergences too fast?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am training a video prediction model.

According to the loss plots, the model convergences very fast while the final loss is not small enough and the generation is not good.

Actually,  I have test the `lr=1e-04`and `lr=1e-05`, the loss plots drop down a little more slowly, but it's still not ideal. But I think `lr=1e-05` should be small enough, isn't it?

How should I fix my model or the hyper parameters?

Comment: I've recently noticed there's an AI StackExchange, I think you might get better answers there : https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your [big pile of linear algebra](https://xkcd.com/1838/) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with different LR. You might be going too fast and falling into a local optima, or going too slow and never finding your global optima.

Before adjusting your network make sure it is not a problem with the LR. GL!